# Build section not found in Xcode4

Tags: ios, xcode4

i was working with Xcode3, since i moved to Xcode4, i didn't find where is the Build in the settings section in Xcode as it looks like this in Xcode3:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to understand your question, the 'Build Settings' is still there in XCode4, simply click on your project itself and it's there

[image: XCode4 Build Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the project at the top of the left pane in XCode and you will find a 'Build Settings' pane...